# using definePlugin to pass constants to dependent packages

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-2

I have three projects configured this way:

1. Main app

   2. Module A
   3. Module B

On my main app, I'm using DefinePlugin to pass my dependent modules an API URL, like this:

```
//webpack-1
loaders:[{
    test:/\.jsx?$/,
    exclude: /(node_modules)/,
    loader: "babel",
    query: {
        presets:["es2015","stage-2","react"]
    }
}],
plugins:[new webpack.DefinePlugin({"API_URL":"http://www.google.com"})]
```

Then, within my modules A & B, I could use this constant like this

```
axios.get(`${API_URL}/getProducts`).then(response=>console.log(response));
```

I've migrated to webpack v2 so my code config file changes to:

```
//webpack-2
rules:[{
    test:/\.jsx?$/,
    exclude: /(node_modules)/,
    loader: "babel",
    options: {
        presets:["es2015","stage-2","react"]
    }
}],
plugins:[new webpack.DefinePlugin({"API_URL":"http://www.google.com"})]
```

but when I try to use API_URL on my dependent modules I get the following error:

```
ReferenceError:API_URL is not defined
```

What am I doing wrong? What else do I need to configure?

Comment: can you try to log `console.log(API_URL)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main webpack config needs to be configured like this:

```
    plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        API_URL:"http://www.google.com"
        PRODUCTION: JSON.stringify(true),
        VERSION: JSON.stringify("5fa3b9"),
        BROWSER_SUPPORTS_HTML5: true,
        TWO: "1+1"
    })]
```

Then, on your dependent package, you can do so:

```
console.log('%c DEPENDENT APP! ', 'background: #222; color: #bada55');
console.info("Production:", PRODUCTION);
console.info("Version:", VERSION);
console.info("HTML5 support:", BROWSER_SUPPORTS_HTML5);
console.info("Two:", TWO);
```

I've made a [github repo](https://github.com/anyulled/package-dependency) with a proof of concept demonstrating how to implement it.